# Find out unfixed exploits count based on application version

Tags: security, patch-management, exploit

In our enviroment we are often required to run old outdated versions of different applications, and im wondering about the security implications on that. So im hoping there is a site that basicly lists AppXX1 version V2 has X known exploits.

Im off course thinking about bigger applications like Java, IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Secunia](http://secunia.com/) has an application /OS / hardware appliance vulnerability database which has the info you are looking for.

[IE6 Report page](http://secunia.com/advisories/product/11/?task=statistics) for example.

[alt text http://secunia.com/advisories/graph/?type=sol&period=all&prod=11](http://secunia.com/advisories/graph/?type=sol&period=all&prod=11)

and [Java JRE 1.2.x](http://secunia.com/advisories/product/785/?task=statistics)

[alt text http://secunia.com/advisories/graph/?type=sol&period=all&prod=785](http://secunia.com/advisories/graph/?type=sol&period=all&prod=785)

Answer (score 2):

I think something like the Nessus vulnerability list is probably going to be your best bet, but I'm not sure how to do that without running Nessus itself.  `cve.mitre.org` has the most comprehensive list of vulnerabilities, but I've never looked for a list organised by software product, so I don't know if there's anything like that there.